# Quickly increase/decrease cell value by 1 in Numbers

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, iwork-numbers

Is there a quick way to increase/decrease a cell value by 1 in Apple iWork's Numbers?

Answer (score 2):

Numbers provides an interface for AppleScript. Open *Automator.app* and create a new *Service*. Here, drag *Run AppleScript* from the left to the right pane.

Now, paste the following AppleScript with a bit of copypasta [from here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3964938?start=0&tstart=0):

```
tell application "Numbers"
    set tTables to (tables of sheets of front document whose its selection range is not missing value)
    repeat with t in tTables -- tables of each sheet
        if contents of t is not {} then -- the list is not empty, it's the selected sheet
            set tCells to cells of selection range of (get item 1 of t) -- selection in active table
            repeat with i in tCells -- each selected cell
                set val to value of i
                set value of i to (val + 1)
            end repeat
            return
        end if
    end repeat
end tell
```

Save this workflow as *Increase Cell Value* or similar. Close the service and create another one. Now, do the same again, but change `val + 1` to `val - 1`, and save it as *Decrease Cell Value*.

Finally, go to *System Preferences » Keyboard » Keyboard Shortcuts*. Here, under *Services*, assign a keyboard shortcut to your new actions, for example <kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> to increase and <kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> to decrease.

[image]

Once this is done, you can just select any number of (numeric) cells in Numbers and hit your (global) keyboard shortcut.

Before and after:

[image]
[image]

Your services are also available through the Numbers menu:

[image]

Of course, one could do some further error checking for cells that contain text, but you get the idea.

Comment: Brill, I'll try it out now, I don't suppose you know how to get the value of one cell depending on if another cell of the same row matches a particular value?

Comment: The AppleScript suite allows you to traverse rows and columns, e.g. combining `repeat with c in …` and accessing cells like `cell 1 of row 2 of table 1 of sheet 1`, but I'd rather do this with built-in functions in Numbers itself if possible. But I'm not a spreadsheet expert so I'm not sure which functions you'd need, sorry.

Comment: I've created the services but the shortcuts do not work and they are not listed under the services menu. I have restarted Numbers too.

Comment: It works for me. Have you made sure the keyboard shortcut isn't used by anything else? For example, I use `⌥⌘I` to increase and `⌥⇧⌘I` to decrease and it works right away.